# Install F# 4.1 SDK on build server

Tags: f#, sdk, msbuild

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 with F# support on my PC and I have MSBuild targets in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\FSharp` and F# 4.1 SDK in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1`

I have installed Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (from https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15 ) but there is no option to install F# SDK so building F# projects using MSBuild 15 fails.

How can I install F# 4.1 SDK without installing Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short term fix until the SDK can be installed separately is to add a directive to the project file to look in the NuGet packages folder for the Microsoft.FSharp.Targets file.  Here are steps I took to fix this:

Ensure your using the new F# project from VS.NET 2017 as its has this directive:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\FSharp.Compiler.Tools.4.1.17\build\FSharp.Compiler.Tools.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\FSharp.Compiler.Tools.4.1.17\build\FSharp.Compiler.Tools.props')" />
```

Replace this section of the project file:

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition="$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &gt;= 4.3.0.0 AND $(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &lt; 4.3.1.0 ">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition="$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &gt;= 4.3.1.0 AND $(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &lt; 4.4.0.0 ">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition="$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &gt;= 4.4.0.0 AND $(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &lt; 4.4.1.0 ">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

With this XML:

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &gt;= 4.3.0.0 AND $(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &lt; 4.3.1.0 ">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition="$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &gt;= 4.3.1.0 AND $(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &lt; 4.4.0.0 ">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition="$(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &gt;= 4.4.0.0 AND $(TargetFSharpCoreVersion) &lt; 4.4.1.0 ">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.1\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
  <!-- This is needed for TeamCity where F# SDK is only available via NuGet right now - hopefully can be removed at some point once the SDK is available for install -->
   <PropertyGroup Condition="!Exists('$(FSharpTargetsPath)')">
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(FscToolPath)\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Ensure you build server has a restore NuGet packages step prior to doing the build

Ensure you packages file includes: FSharp.Compiler.Tools and FSharp.Core

The reason this works is as follows:
This checks to see if the FSharpTargetsPath exists and if not use the packages folder as the source.  You don't want to always use the packages folder otherwise on a fresh checkout on a users machine the packages aren't available and the build will fail.  For this to work on the build server this assumes you have a step to restore the NuGet packages PRIOR to doing the build.

Comment: Works for us. It was enough to add Fsharp.Compiler.Tools nuget. It added import statement automatically and add the only change needed was the conditional import (last in your snippet)

Answer (score 4):

There is an MSI that can be installed, it's not yet been published on MSDN.
But it will be shortly.

You can track the issue here: on GitHub:

"Deploy FSharp Tools MSI to MSDN #2553"
https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/2553

Kevin Ransom

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's so new things haven't been updated yet.

- Four step process for installing for a build server (scroll down to Option 3)

http://fsharp.org/use/windows/

(4.0)

- According to the MSDN blog...

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/07/announcing-f-4-1-and-the-visual-f-tools-for-visual-studio-2017-2/

[image: from blog post]

Seems you at least need .NET Core / CLI

- Searching on Microsoft's site doesn't seem to find anything...

[image]

Closest thing would be the 4.0 tools:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48179

- There are alse the raw NuGet packages (4.1)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Compiler.Tools
https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core

- Bottom line: I think its so new it hasn't been released in a format similar to previous versions yet.  I'll keep checking every 24 hours to see if they update it on their website.