# How to Check .Net and F# Core Versions on Target System

Tags: f#, .net-framework-version

I have written a simple F# console applet. It is built against .Net Framework 4.5 and F Sharp Core 4.0. It runs fine on my Windows 10 workstation. On Windows Server 2016 (Version 1607) it throws

**Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$VolLib>.$VolLib' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

I have tried the substitutions suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679193/install-f-4-1-sdk-on-build-server/43919448). I still get the same error.

I can install a kit on the server (target machine). I just don't know what to install.

Comment: F# problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679193/install-f-4-1-sdk-on-build-server/43919448                                                                                                                                 Check .Net Framework installations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Comment: @RyanWilson Tried and edited OP to reflect result, which was no change, same error.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a binding issue, not a framework issue. 4.3 is the older version.

Most likely, the 4.3 version is installed in the GAC of the server. Less likely, the bin dir contains the wrong F# version, but the offending method is not called on the Win10 system. Check the output dir and the GAC for the `FSharp.Core.dll` versions, if they are correct, check `BindingRedirect` in `app.config`.

If this doesn't help finding the location and version of the wrongly linked dll, alternatively, dump the Core assembly version with `typeof<option>.Assembly.GetName().Version` as one of the earliest in your code (use `Console.WriteLine`, not `printfn`). You can also dump the actual path of the location of the assembly this way.

The usual reason this happens is because your code compiles with a library that itself is compiled against an older version of FSharp.Core (like for instance FParsec, it's a common issue with that library). I've had cases where the wrong assembly was then deployed, or the right one, but without the `BindingRedirect` it failed anyway.

If you want to know which linked assembly is the culprit, you'll have to check for each of them what F# version they've been compiled against. A tool like Reflector can help. If you you want to dig deeper into the assembly loading resolution, you can use the `fuslogvw.exe` tool for real time logging of binding events.

Btw, you can get the current version of the framework you're running in with `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription`

Comment: I'm finding tons of C# Support under Assembly on the server, so now I will go find out how to install F# support.

Comment: Should I just add my F# DLLs to the GAC?

Comment: There is no FSharp.Core.dll on the server.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus, if your application uses `FSharp.Core` (which it does if it is compiled with F#), then you should deploy `FSharp.Core.dll` with it. This is also true if your project relies on a library that itself relies on `FSharp.Core`. The error shown suggests your code does rely on it. I don't know how you deploy, but you should make sure that the `FSharp.Core.dll` you find in the bin directory of your project, also gets deployed. Oh, and **do not put FSharp.Core.dll in the GAC**, I only mentioned that here because it is the cause of many problems like these. Just copy the file :).